# Why directive may not be used on INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I try to set length limit to my graphQl schema via directive

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  directive @length(max: Int!) on FIELD_DEFINITION

  type Book {
    id: ID
    title: String
    author: String
    pages: Float 
  }
  
  input PagesInput {
    pages: Float @length(max: 10)
  }
  
  type Mutation {
    changePages(bookId: ID, pagesInput: PagesInput): Book
  }
`;
```

after it I made custom function lengthDirective using apollo [instructions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/custom-scalars/).
This function works properly if I set directive to Books type (not to input).
But if I set it to input (where I really need it), I receive an error:

```
Error: Directive "@length" may not be used on INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION.
```

Why it that? How can I set up directive to input type?

Comment: As you are applying the directive on an input field, directive @length(max: Int!) on FIELD_DEFINITION should be changed to directive @length(max: Int!) on INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION